# Synthesize SPS and PPS for incomplete H264 stream for iOS VideoToolbox

Tags: ios, h.264, video-toolbox

I have an AXIS IP camera (M1054) which sends an H264/RTP stream via RTSP.

Unfortunately, they do not send SPS and PPS NALUs at all, they only transfer (fragmented) Codec slices.

I'm trying to decode that stream with the iOS `VideoToolbox` framework which needs the H264 SPS and PPS tuple to correctly setup the `CMFormatDescription`.

I wonder how I can synthesize the necessary parameter sets from looking at the actual H264 slices?

*Update*: I have captured an example session where `mplayer` manages to display the stream via Wireshark. The capture file [is here](https://www.vanille.de/data/axis-rtsp-session2.pcapng) and you can see the whole RTSP setup as well as a couple of seconds RTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTP consists of 3 sets of flows.

1. RTP for the media
2. RTSP for controlling the connection
3. RTCP for the sender confirmation and timestamps.

Although the SPS/PPS is often in band inside the stream and is transported via RTP - it doesn't need to be there (and may be shouldn't be there). The SPS/PPS is transmitted as part of the setup process (RTSP). I usually recommend running http://www.live555.com/ in the debugger to learn about the details of the process - but http://www.live555.com/ is currently down.

In very rare circumstances you could recreate the SPS/PPS from a well known constrained H.264 stream. But in general you can't. So the SPS/PPS are metadata of the H.264 stream that is not redundantly stored anywhere else.

So if your familiarize yourself with the setup process - RTSP - it will be pretty obvious.

Comment: Is it the line `a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; profile-level-id=420029; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAKeKQCgDLYC3AQEBpB4kRUA==,aM48gA==`? If so, how would I be able to encode this as SPS and PPS NALUs, which is what iOS/VideoToolbox needs?

Comment: Further inspection shows that `sprop-parameters-sets` is indeed the base64 encoded version of the SPS and PPS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any advice on what exactly is in there, how to decode or encode the sprop-parameter-sets? I cant find any practical info on how to get that if you're doing custom video encoding in code.

Comment: sprop-parameter-sets are well defined in specifications and  http://www.live555.com/ is a great sample implementation that contains encode and decode. I am not sure what other advice you are looking for.